# SQLite insert problem on Objective-C (NSInternalInconsistencyException)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, insert

The error message is:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error on insert'

I've already tested the insert on my DB with SQLiteManager and it works fine.

This is my code:

```
-(void) insertImage:(int) idImage
              title:(NSString *) title 
        description:(NSString *) desc 
                URL:(NSString *) URL 
           ImageURL:(NSString *) imageURL 
               date:(NSString *) date{

    char *errorMsg;
    sqlite3 *database;

    if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO tb_test VALUES( \'?\', \'?\', \'?\', \'?\', \'?\', \'?\');"];
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

        sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, idImage);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [title UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [desc UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [URL UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [iamgeURL UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [date UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        }


//        NSLog(@"sqlite3_step(stmt) = %d", sqlite3_step(stmt));

        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
           NSAssert1(0, @"Error on insert", errorMsg);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

        sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
        sqlite3_close(database);

    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you writing SQL by hand?  A waste of time.  At least use FMDB.  A better solution would be to use Core Data directly (and that'll give you better iCloud integration in the future, too).

Comment: I just used that because it's my first application e I didn't know about the core data before I start programming...btw this is an application that is almost exactly the same of one made to android, and there I've used SQLite too.

Comment: Portability is one reason to use SQLite directly, but, even then, iCloud integration may drive you to Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% but I don't think you should be putting `'` around your tokens. Therefore you may wish to try this

```
NSString *insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO tb_test VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

When you bind e.g. `sqlite3_bind_text` it SQLite performs the appropriate escaping/quoting required.

Comment: No...this isn't the error...i still can't insert anything on my database with statements...